# What is Cocoa Studio

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, sdk

I heard about cocoa studio from a friend of mine so i was curious to find out its details.....According to him issues of memory handling are decreased by its use..Now first of all i don't know what is it. Is it a 3rd Party SDK of framework? I tried to google around for information but currently their site is under maintenance and i was not able to gather any substantial information from other resources.

So can anybody enlighten me about its details.Any links suggestions,information would be appreciated...

Thanks

Aditya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa Studio is not a tool, Its name of the training course by "The Pragmatic Studio",The  course is aimed at developers planning on building GUI applications on the Mac or the iPhone.

For More Information, have a look at: -

1. [cocoa_studio](http://www.pcworld.com/article/150730/cocoa_studio_coming_to_denver_in_october.html)
2. [The Pragmatic Studio](http://pragmaticstudio.com/mac)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are talking about *cocos2d*. It is a graphics library for *iPhone* and some other platforms.

http://cocos2d.org/

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/